# Input a number until -1

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

> Create a program that asks the user to input numbers (integers). The program prints "Type numbers” until the user types the number -1. When the user types the number -1, the program prints "Thank you and see you later!" and ends.

This is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TheSumOfSetOfNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number=0, sum=0, count=0, even=0, odd=0;
        double average=0;
        System.out.println("Type numbers:  ");


        while(true)
        {
            number=Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
            if(number==(-1)) break;

        }

    }
```

*When I check it, this is the error : 
remember to read user input with Integer.parseInt( reader.nextLine() ); 
call it only once!*

If I only call it once, how it will be possible to scan a lot numbers?

Comment: I believe the error is saying call it only once within the loop

Comment: My problem is the following: I think my algorhytm works well, I would like to know, if somebody came across with that bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you will use in this scenario. Using a do while loop, you can get your output

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter Numbers");
        num = scan.nextInt();
    
    } while (num != -1);

    System.out.println("Thanks ! See you later");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are always typing numbers I will use this:

```
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

boolean exit = false;
System.out.println("Type numbers:");
while (!exit){
    if (scanner.nextInt() != -1)
        exit = true;
}

System.out.println("Thank you and see you later!");
```

But you have to call scanner object each time you would like to read something from the imput.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: This runs until the user enters -1:

```
while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    if (number == -1) {
        System.out.println("Thank you and see you later!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should probably use `hasNextLine`

Comment: true , but works with hasNext() as well it looks for next token/input, Ediiting to be better Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to put `System.out.println("Type numbers:  ");` inside while loop.
2. Since you are giving only integers as input, no need to parse it.

Below is required code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TheSumOfSetOfNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number=0, sum=0, count=0, even=0, odd=0;
        double average=0;
        // we need to loop "Type numbers:" each time umtil "-1" is pressed
        while(number != -1)
        {
            System.out.println("Type numbers:  ");
            number=reader.nextInt();
        }
        // user must have been typed "-1" therefore it exits from whle loop
        System.out.println("Thank you and see you later!");
        // now there is nothing in main() fxn, therefore, the program will stop
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Type numbers:  
1
Type numbers:
3
Type numbers:  
8
Type numbers:  
9
Type numbers:  
0
Type numbers:  
-1
Thank you and see you later!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = -1;

   do {
     System.out.println("Welcome to Java Programming!");
     System.out.println("Print Again? (y/n)");
     num = input.nextLine();
   }   while (num.equalsIgnoreCase(-1));
  }
 }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int flag=0,n;
        while(flag!=1){
            n=sc.nextInt();
            if(n==-1){
                flag=1;
            }
        }
    System.out.print("Thank you and see you later!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).